# .htaccess problems with redirect godaddy linux hosting

Tags: .htaccess

Having some problems with my .htaccess, still new to this. Specifically the .php file extension is not being removed and the write of blog/something/ for article.php?title=something is not working. Also if there are any other tips or errors you see please point them out.

```
# generic rules
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect to 404 page when requested file does not exist
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# ----------------------------------------------------- /
# URL rewrites
# ----------------------------------------------------- /

# http://www.example.com => http://example.com/ (remove the www)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# http://example.com/index.php => http://example.com/ (remove index.php)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

# http://example.com/article.php?title=something => http://example.com/blog/something (user's link was for http://example.com/blog/something)
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-z0-9-]+)/$ /article.php?title=$1 [QSA]

# http://example.com/page.php => http://example.com/page/ (remove .php file extension)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Try changing last line to: `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 4 rewrite sections' comments are misleading at best, and at worst indicate that you don't understand the concept of SEO URI's.

1. change www.domain.tld to domain.tld  -- OK, standard practice
2. remove a trailing `index.php` from the INcoming URI. I'm not sure what the point of this is, but your code should work. The user or search engine should see the address without index.php.
3. you are actually changing an INCOMING /blog/..id.. into /article.php?title=..id.. . A few notes: your pages need to generate links with the /blog format. .htaccess simply changes that into something that the server can digest. Second, you require a trailing / after the ..id... If you want to make it *optional*, use /? . Third, any incoming Query String will be discarded, since you are specifying a new Query String (title= ) and don't have a [QSA] flag. Fourth, the [L] is unnecessary (but harmless), as a RewriteCond is not in effect.
4. again, possible confusion between the INcoming URI and what server-acceptable form you're changing it to. Is the user expected to give you the form ..page../ and you're turning it into a PHP file ..page.php? If so, why the trailing /? It tells the server that this is a directory, not a file. Again, on the input, you are requiring a trailing / (use /? to make it optional).

At the very least, your comments need clarifying about what you expect as input from the user (or links on your site), and what you're turning them into.

Comment: number 3 the incoming should be something like blog/some-title and added the qsa flag also places a ? .php so it can be a trailing slash or not